# C programming: Basic fscanf issues with doubles

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having some issues with `fscanf`. I'm very new to C but I cannot seem to get `fscanf` to load the correct information from a .txt file.

```
int main() {

    //Vars
    FILE *tempFileIn;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int objectIdNum;
    double magnitudePhotographed;
    double distance;
    int velocity;
    double magnitudeCorrected;
    double magnitudeTotal;

    //Read File Data
    tempFileIn = fopen("hubbleData.txt","r");
    if (tempFileIn == NULL) {
        printf("File read error.");
    }

    printHeaders();
    while(!feof(tempFileIn)) {
        fscanf(tempFileIn, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &objectIdNum, &distance, &velocity, &magnitudeCorrected, &magnitudeTotal);
        printf( "%2.3f      %2.3f", velocity, distance);
        printf("\n");
        rowIndex++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The velocity is getting printed as expected but distance is always printed as 0.0000. If I switch the print order of the two, distance will be printed correctly and the velocity will be printed as 0.0000.  I'm only concerned about the second and third columns but have to scan all of them as per the project guidelines.

```
Input format:
1      0.032    +170      1.5      -16.0
2      0.034    +290      0.5       17.2
6822   0.214    -130      9.0       12.7
598    0.263    -70       7.0       15.1
221    0.275    -185      8.8       13.4
224    0.275    -220      5.0       17.2
5457   0.45     +200      9.9       13.3

Actual Output:                
170.000      0.000
290.000      0.000
-130.000      0.000
-70.000      0.000
-185.000      0.000
-220.000      0.000
 200.000      0.000

Expected Output:
170.000      0.032
290.000      0.034
-130.000      0.214
-70.000      0.263
-185.000      0.275
-220.000      0.275
 200.000      0.45
```

Comment: show how data is stored in file

Comment: we need to see the whole code/what you input into your program.

Comment: Added requested information @555k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`velocity` is declared `int` but used like a `double` in your `fscanf()` and `printf()` calls. You probably meant to declare it as `double`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I posted this comment before the user posted the types of velocity and distance.  I assumed velocity and distance were an incompatible type of float, not an integer.

Try this:

```
printf( "%2.3f      %2.3f", (float)velocity, (float)distance);
```

My guess is that you are passing variables into printf that are not the same size as floats, and so the second part of "velocity" is printed instead of distance.  Printf uses the stack to pass variables and the number and size of variables are not defined by the function, so any size mismatches will cause problems like this.

Comment: the float cast gives me 0's for velocity. @c.fogelklou
    
    0.000      0.032
    0.000      0.034
    0.000      0.214
    0.000      0.263
    0.000      0.275
    0.000      0.275
    0.000      0.450

Comment: You get 0.000 for velocity because it is originally an integer in your source code.  You didn't post this at first so I assumed it was a type of float.  You also need velocity to be a float type, otherwise it can't hold values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `objectIdNum` and `velocity` as `double` so that `fscanf` and `printf` will work correctly.

you declared variable `velocity` as `int` and is using wrong format specifier in `fscanf` and in `printf`

Answer (score 0):

you need 3 changes

1) Declare `velocity` as `double`.

2) in `fscanf`, `objectIdNum` should be read as `%d` not `%lf`.

finally use `flose(tempFileIn);` before returning from main(exiting the program).

note: i assume `velocity` as `double` because practically `velocity` is a `real` number and not a `integral` value.